# "Content is not allowed in prolog" error while calling web service using ws-security

Tags: java, xml, web-services, soap, ws-security

I have created a client using ws-import and implemented SOAPHandler for ws-security. Now I'm facing xml parse error.

Can anyone please guide me on what is the issue and solving it. Thanks in advance.

Below is the error message.

```
Exception in thread "main" com.sun.xml.internal.ws.protocol.soap.MessageCreationException: Couldn't create SOAP message due to exception: XML reader error: javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: ParseError at [row,col]:[1,1]
Message: Content is not allowed in prolog.
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.encoding.SOAPBindingCodec.decode(SOAPBindingCodec.java:348)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.client.HttpTransportPipe.createResponsePacket(HttpTransportPipe.java:254)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.client.HttpTransportPipe.process(HttpTransportPipe.java:203)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.client.HttpTransportPipe.processRequest(HttpTransportPipe.java:122)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.DeferredTransportPipe.processRequest(DeferredTransportPipe.java:95)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.__doRun(Fiber.java:626)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.api.pipe.Fiber._doRun(Fiber.java:585)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.doRun(Fiber.java:570)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.runSync(Fiber.java:467)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.Stub.process(Stub.java:308)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.SEIStub.doProcess(SEIStub.java:163)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(SyncMethodHandler.java:98)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(SyncMethodHandler.java:78)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.SEIStub.invoke(SEIStub.java:135)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy22.getCustBankDetails(Unknown Source)
    at com.axis.MainClass.main(MainClass.java:74)
Caused by: com.sun.xml.internal.ws.streaming.XMLStreamReaderException: XML reader error: javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: ParseError at [row,col]:[1,1]
Message: Content is not allowed in prolog.
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.streaming.XMLStreamReaderUtil.wrapException(XMLStreamReaderUtil.java:256)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.streaming.XMLStreamReaderUtil.next(XMLStreamReaderUtil.java:84)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.streaming.XMLStreamReaderUtil.nextContent(XMLStreamReaderUtil.java:99)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.streaming.XMLStreamReaderUtil.nextElementContent(XMLStreamReaderUtil.java:89)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.encoding.StreamSOAPCodec.decode(StreamSOAPCodec.java:164)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.encoding.StreamSOAPCodec.decode(StreamSOAPCodec.java:292)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.encoding.StreamSOAPCodec.decode(StreamSOAPCodec.java:118)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.encoding.SOAPBindingCodec.decode(SOAPBindingCodec.java:343)
    ... 15 more
Caused by: javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: ParseError at [row,col]:[1,1]
Message: Content is not allowed in prolog.
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLStreamReaderImpl.next(XMLStreamReaderImpl.java:598)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.util.xml.XMLStreamReaderFilter.next(XMLStreamReaderFilter.java:81)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.streaming.XMLStreamReaderUtil.next(XMLStreamReaderUtil.java:65)
    ... 21 more
```

Below is the code, the stub is generated by wsimport

### Main class

```
TestincomeTransformService service = new TestincomeTransformService();
TestincomeTransformInterface  in = service.getTestincomeTransformPort();
GetCustBankDetails parameters = new GetCustBankDetails();    

GetCustBankDetailsRequest bankrequest = new GetCustBankDetailsRequest();
bankrequest.setCustomerId("123");
parameters.setGetCustBankDetailsRequest(bankrequest);

THeader subHeader = new THeader(); 

subHeader.setChannelId("IBB");

Holder<THeader> holder = new Holder<THeader>();    
holder.value = subHeader;

GetCustBankDetailsResponse  response = in.getCustBankDetails(parameters, holder);
```

### Handler class (I have removed the properties values)

```
Properties prop=null;


public WSSecurityHandler () throws Exception {

     prop = new Properties();

     prop.put("org.apache.ws.security.crypto.provider", "org.apache.ws.security.components.crypto.Merlin");
     prop.put("org.apache.ws.security.crypto.merlin.keystore.type", "");
     prop.put("org.apache.ws.security.crypto.merlin.keystore.password", "");
     prop.put("org.apache.ws.security.crypto.merlin.keystore.alias", "");
     prop.put("org.apache.ws.security.crypto.merlin.file", "");
     prop.put("alias", "");
     prop.put("password", "");

    }


 public Set<QName> getHeaders() {

     System.out.println("Setting headers");
     Set<QName> HEADERS = new HashSet<QName>();

     HEADERS.add(new QName(WSConstants.WSSE_NS, "Security"));
     HEADERS.add(new QName(WSConstants.WSSE_NS, "Security"));
     HEADERS.add(new QName(WSConstants.ENC_NS, "EncryptedData"));

     return HEADERS;

 }


 public boolean handleMessage(SOAPMessageContext messageContext) {

     try {

         SOAPMessage msg = messageContext.getMessage();


        // is outgoing?
       Boolean isOutGoing = (Boolean) messageContext.get(MessageContext.MESSAGE_OUTBOUND_PROPERTY);

         if (isOutGoing) {


             // if it is outgoing code and sign
             EncryptUtil.EncryptSOAPEnvelope(msg, prop);
             EncryptUtil.SignSOAPEnvelope(msg, prop);


         } else { 
             // if it is incooming decode and check signature.
             EncryptUtil.CheckSignatureAndDecode(msg, this, prop);

         }


     } catch (Exception ex) {
         System.out.println("Exception"+ex);
         ex.printStackTrace();
     }

     return true;

 }


 public boolean handleFault(SOAPMessageContext messageContext) {

     return true;
 }


 @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
 public void handle(Callback[] callbacks) throws IOException,

        UnsupportedCallbackException {

     String password;

     for (Callback cb : callbacks) {

         if (cb instanceof WSPasswordCallback) {

              WSPasswordCallback pc = (WSPasswordCallback) cb;

             try {

                 password = prop.getProperty("password");

             } catch (Exception e) {


                 throw new UnsupportedCallbackException(pc,  "failure recovering the key in the properties");

             }

            if (pc.getIdentifer() != null) 
            {
                 pc.setPassword(password);
            } 
        } 
     } 
 }

 public void close(MessageContext messageContext) {

 }
```

Comment: which code are you referring, the handler one? I have created stub using wsimport, i'm not creating the soap message by myself. But i'm confused with XML reader error

Comment: A little bit more information could help to solve the problem. How do you call your webservice? SoapUI, programmatically with a client? "Content is not allowed in prolog" looks like a problem regarding the byte order flags. Nothing special with ws-security.

Comment: Can you check the wsdl with a hex-editor to ensure there ist no BOM?

Comment: @Frank i guess you mean no char before <?xml right ? There are no char's before it.

Comment: No, I mean the invisible bytes for the byte order mark. You can see them only in a hex editor. Another reason could be the encoding of the wsdl-file itself and the encoding-attribute in the xml-header.

Comment: @Frank I checked in hex editor, there are no extra bytes

Comment: Sorry @Frank I could not quite understand your statement "Another reason could be the encoding of the wsdl-file itself and the encoding-attribute in the xml-header"

Comment: Your wsdl has `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>` or something similar. And the file itself has a encoding. Check if this matches. I had problems with this once resulting in the dreaded "Content not allowed in prolog".

Comment: Yes the wsdl has <?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?> and no BOM. I had tested the same in SOAUP UI where its working fine.

Comment: Can anyone please help me around this